# Mongoose/Mongodb previous and next in embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm learning Mongodb/Mongoose/Express and have come across a fairly complex query (relative to my current level of understanding anyway) that I'm not sure how best to approach. I have a collection - to keep it simple let's call it entities - with an embedded actions array:

```
name: String
actions: [{
  name: String
  date: Date
}]
```

What I'd like to do is to return an array of documents with each containing the most recent action (or most recent to a specified date), and the next action (based on the same date).

Would this be possible with one find() query, or would I need to break this down into multiple queries and merge the results to generate one result array? I'm looking for the most efficient route possible.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your "actions" are inserted with the "most recent" being the last entry in the list, and usually this will be the case unless you are specifically updating items and changing dates, then all you really want to do is "project" the last item of the array. This is what the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection operation is for:

```
Model.find({},{ "actions": { "$slice": -1 } },function(err,docs) {
    // contains an array with the last item
});
```

If indeed you are "updating" array items and changing dates, but you want to query for the most recent on a regular basis, then you are probably best off keeping the array ordered. You can do this with a few modifiers such as:

```
Model.update(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("541f7bbb699e6dd5a7caf2d6"),
    },
    {
        "$push": { "actions": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "date": 1 } } }
    },
    function(err,numAffected) {

    }
);
```

Which is actually more of a *trick* that you can do with the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier to simply sort the existing array elements without adding or removing. In versions prior to 2.6 you need the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) *"update"* modifier in here as well, but this could be set to a value larger than the expected array elements if you did not actually want to restrict the possible size, but that is probably a good idea.

Unfortunately, if you were "updating" via a [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) statement, then you cannot do this "sorting" in a single update statement, as MongoDB will not allow both types of operations on the array at once. But if you can live with that, then this is a way to keep the array ordered so the first query form works.

If it just seems too hard to keep an array ordered by date, then you can in fact retrieve the largest value my means of the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. This allows greater manipulation of the documents than is available to basic queries, at a little more cost:

```
Model.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array to de-normalize as documents
    { "$unwind": "$actions" },

    // Sort the contents per document _id and inner date
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "actions.date": 1 } },

    // Group back with the "last" element only
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$last": "$name" },
        "actions": { "$last": "$actions" }
    }}
],
function(err,docs) {


})
```

And that will "pull apart" the array using the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator, then process with a next stage to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the contents by "date". In the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage the "_id" means to use the original document key to "collect" on, and the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator picks the field values from the "last" document ( de-normalized ) on that grouping boundary.

So there are various things that you can do, but of course the best way is to keep your array ordered and use the basic projection operators to simply get the last item in the list.

Comment: Finally got back to this project. I think you may have misunderstood me (unless I'm just not seeing how this relates to my problem) as you're just getting the action with the maximum date for each document. What I'm looking for is to retrieve the next action and the previous action, based on a date. So if entity with name "A" had actions with dates of Jan 1st, Jan 2nd and Jan 4th, and the date is Jan 3rd, I'd be looking to retrieve: {name: "A", prev_action: {date: "Jan 2nd", ...}, next_action: {date: "Jan 4th", ...}}

Comment: @jrwebdev Quote: "What I'd like to do is to return an array of documents with each containing the most recent action (or most recent to a specified date), and the next action (based on the same date)." So you need your array elements to be in order somehow which is exactly what is discusses.